# How to get rid of this boilerplate code in this sealed class hierarchy?

Tags: kotlin, sealed-class

Suppose I've got a `sealed class` hierarchy like that:

```
sealed class A {
    abstract val x: Int
    abstract fun copyX(x1: Int): A
}

data class A1(override val x: Int, val s1: String) : A() {
    override fun copyX(x1: Int): A {
        return this.copy(x = x1)
    }
}

data class A2(override val x: Int, val s2: String) : A() {
    override fun copyX(x1: Int): A {
        return this.copy(x = x1)
    }
}
```

All the data classes have field `x` and should provide method `copyX(x1: Int)` to copy all the fields but `x` and override `x` with `x1`. For instance,

```
fun foo(a: A): A { a.copyX(100) }
```

The definitions above probably work but the repeating `copyX` across all the data classes seem very clumsy. How would you suggest get rid of this repeated `copyX` ?

Comment: May I ask what your real-life usecase is for this? I've had similar problems in the past, and I usually either repeated the declarations like this, or found a complete other way. It looks like you want to abstract the subclasses by using this sealed class, and yet you still want to retain the subclass's implementation when copying, so I wonder what your need is exacly.

Comment: @Joffrey I am afraid the actual use case is a bit too complicated to describe now. Thanks for asking though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you can implement `copyX` as an extension (or even `A`'s member) so as to concentrate the code in one place and avoid at least duplicating the `copyX` function in the sealed class subtypes:

```
sealed class A {
    abstract val x: Int
}

fun A.copyX(x1: Int): A = when (this) {
    is A1 -> copy(x = x1)
    is A2 -> copy(x = x1) 
}

data class A1(override val x: Int, val s1: String) : A()

data class A2(override val x: Int, val s2: String) : A()
```

If you have a lot of sealed subtypes and all of them are `data` classes or have a `copy` function, you could also copy them generically with reflection. For that, you would need to get the [`primaryConstructor`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect.full/primary-constructor.html) or the function named `copy` from the `KClass`, then fill the arguments for the call, finding the `x` parameter by name and putting the `x1` value for it, and putting the values obtained from `component1()`, `component2()` etc. calls or leaving the default values for the other parameters. It would look like this:

```
fun A.copyX(x1: Int): A {
    val copyFunction = this::class.memberFunctions.single { it.name == "copy" }
    val args = mapOf(
        copyFunction.instanceParameter!! to this,
        copyFunction.parameters.single { it.name == "x" } to x1
    )
    return copyFunction.callBy(args) as A
}
```

This works because `callBy` allows omitting the optional arguments.

Note that it requires a dependency on `kotlin-reflect` and works only with Kotlin/JVM. Also, reflection has some performance overhead, so it's not suitable for performance-critical code. You could optimize this by using the Java reflection (`this::class.java`, `getMethod(...)`) instead (which would be more verbose) and caching the reflection entities.

Comment: I don't like runtime reflection so I won't probably use it but thank you for the detailed answer anyway :))